# Filter a table to return a value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Let imagine, we have this table from column A to C

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Name | Price |
| 10/01/2020 | aa | 5 |
| 10/01/2020 | bb | 5 |
| 15/01/2020 | aa | 5 |

Now I have two lines :

| F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/01/2020 | aa | ? |
| 16/01/2020 | aa | ? |

How can I automatically fill the "?" next to the two lines ?
There is two criteria :

1. column G must match column B (easy with INDEX and MATCH)
2. select the dates larger than F and finally, the smallest date.

Answer (score 1):

Formula for `H1` is

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4,MINIFS($A$2:$A$4,$A$2:$A$4,">="&F1,$B$2:$B$4,G1),$B$2:$B$4,G1)
```

Then copy to `H2`.  It returns 0 for `H2` since 16/01/20 is greater than all of the dates in column A.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Does E1 refers to F1 (and F1 to G1) ? in `">="&E1,$B$2:$B$4,F1`

Comment: I was off a column.  I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 dynamic arrays:

```
=@SORTBY(FILTER($C$2:$C$5,($A$2:$A$5>F1)*($B$2:$B$5=G1),""),FILTER($A$2:$A$5,($A$2:$A$5>F1)*($B$2:$B$5=G1),""))
```

[image]

---

If one has LET() it can be shortened to:

```
=LET(dt,$A$2:$A$5,x,(dt>F1)*($B$2:$B$5=G1),@SORTBY(FILTER($C$2:$C$5,x,""),FILTER(dt,x,"")))
```